# Extracting the tags from an org mode line using Python regex

Tags: python, regex, emacs, org-mode

I would like to extract the three trailing tags from the following org mode line using Python regular expressions:

- TODO [#A] Do something important             :Tag1:Tag2:Tag3:

The following code only recognizes the last tag but puts the other two into the first group

```
import re

m = re.search('(.*)\s*:(.*):$','* TODO [#A] Do something important             :Tag1:Tag2:Tag3:')
print(m.group(1))
print(m.group(2))
```

Result:

- first group: * TODO [#A] Do something important                         :Tag1:Tag2
- second group: Tag3

What do I need to change to have Tags1 and Tag2 to belong to the second group as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `*` is **greedy**. Therefore, `.*` will match as much as it can and still allow the remainder of the regular expression to match. To make the quantifier *non-greedy* you need to add `?` inside the first capture group.

```
import re

s = '* TODO [#A] Do something important :Tag1:Tag2:Tag3:'
m = re.search(r'(.*?)\s*:(.*):$', s)

print "\n".join(m.groups())
```

You could also split here.

```
import re

s = '* TODO [#A] Do something important :Tag1:Tag2:Tag3:'
m = re.split('\s+:|:$', s)

print "\n".join([m[0], m[1]])
```

Output

```
* TODO [#A] Do something important
Tag1:Tag2:Tag3
```

Answer (score 1):

If there aren't any colons in the body of the line, you can just use `split(':')`, like so:

```
>>> s = 'TODO [#A] Do something important :Tag1:Tag2:Tag3:'
>>> s.split(':')
['TODO [#A] Do something important ', 'Tag1', 'Tag2', 'Tag3', '']
>>> s.split(':')[1:-1] # get just the tags
['Tag1', 'Tag2', 'Tag3']
```